# php if file exists include file if not include another file

Tags: php, include, file-exists

I am trying to include a file if it exists, if the file doesn't exist i would like it to include another file instead.

I have the following code which seems to work correctly, The only problem with my code is if the file does exist then it displays them both.

I would like to only include

> include/article.php

if

> include/'.$future.'.php

doesn't exist.

if

> include/'.$future.'.php

exists i don't want to include

> include/article.php

```
<?php
$page = $_GET['include'];
if (file_exists('include/'.$future.'.php')){
   include('include/'.$future.'.php');
}
else{
  include('include/article.php');
 } 
?>
```

Comment: Where does the variable `$future` get it's content from? The way it is right now, it is empty and the file "include/.php" should not exist.

Comment: You must be including `article.php` somewhere else as your logic is sound

Comment: @Sven the $future is not the problem that works, the problem is i don't want both includes at the same time. one or the other.

Comment: Your code cannot include both! Either you are missing something and think your code is working correctly, or the code in your question is not the code you are executing.

Comment: @Sven its defiantly including both files?

Comment: If it does, then there must be another code somewhere that includes the second file. To be sure, add a line `die("Stopped while including the wrong file");` before the `include('include/article.php');` and see if you see that text.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable $future was never even defined, so how is it ever being included? I think you meant for $page and $future to be the same variable.  Also including a file specified by the user in a get request doesn't make much sense to begin with, but is probably also a security risk.

Comment: the $future is defined elsewhere and it includes the file , the problem is i don't want both includes at the sametime. one or the other.

Comment: then most likely the problem is in a part of the code that you didn't post

Comment: @mally *"the $future is defined elsewhere..."* then include your full code in your question then. None of us have the ability to read minds.

Comment: $future just echoes a Y-m-d string example 1912-04-15 so it includes file include/1912-04-15.php

Comment: @mally Now add what you just told me, inside your question. If anyone else comes to visit your question, they will have no idea what it is you are planning to do. What is the exact code for this so-called `$future` string?

Comment: also, if one of the files includes the other, then that would explain why its including both. does one include the other?

Answer (score 0):

> Perhaps this is what you need?
>
> **Make sure any variable you're going to use IS defined before you'll**
>   **use the variable...**

```
<?php
$page = ''; // show emptyness is there is nothing dome below 
$page = isset($_GET['include']); // Do you have a variable in your URL that IS called "include" and is the include variable set? for example: http://www.example.com/index.php?include=.......  you might want to check for empty value and write a default value  as well but I didn't here ;)
// REMEMBER: $future must be defined BEFORE this line!
if (file_exists('include/' . $future . '.php') && is_file('include/' . $future . '.php')){ // file exists on server: true/false and is it a file or a directory? If Directory it will NOT be included as I used is_file()!
   include('include/' . $future . '.php');
   }elseif{
       (file_exists('include/article.php') && is_file('include/article.php')){
           include 'include/article.php';
       }else{
           echo 'WOW, No article found! You just found a error...<br />We will repair all errors ASAP! Thank you for visiting us...';
       }
?>
```